# Programatically retrieving path info for TFS "instrumented binaries" via the data warehouse

Tags: c#, tfs, data-warehouse, tfs-sdk, binaries

Does anyone know how to programatically (using the TFS API) determine what binaries were set to be instrumented as part of a build on TFS?

For example, after running a build on TFS with code coverage it shows this in the output:

```
...
-> 2 binaries instrumented - 62% of all code blocks covered
        SomeAssembly.dll - 392 blocks covered, 368 blocks not covered
        SomeExe.exe - 584 blocks covered, 241 blocks not covered
...
```

I would like to programatically determine that "SomeAssembly.dll" and "SomeExe.exe" are the binaries that were instrumented as part of that build.

I have gotten as far as retrieving the Team Project via the TFS API but am not sure that gets me where I want to go:

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection collection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(versionControlURIRoot + defaultProjectDirectory))
var testManagementService = collection.GetService<ITestManagementService>();
ITestManagementTeamProject teamProject = testManagementService.GetTeamProject(projectName);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution:

Get the Team Project:

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection collection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(versionControlURIRoot + defaultProjectDirectory));
    var testManagementService = collection.GetService<ITestManagementService>();
    ITestManagementTeamProject teamProject = testManagementService.GetTeamProject(projectName);
```

Extract the assembly names from the Build Coverage metadata:

```
List<string> assemblyNames = new List<string>();
if (teamProject != null) {
    ICoverageAnalysisManager coverageAnalysisManager = teamProject.CoverageAnalysisManager;
    if (coverageAnalysisManager != null) {
        IBuildCoverage[] buildCoverage = coverageAnalysisManager.QueryBuildCoverage(buildURI, CoverageQueryFlags.Modules);
        List<string> assemblyNames = new List<string>();
        foreach (IBuildCoverage buildCoverageDetails in buildCoverage) {
            foreach (IModuleCoverage module in buildCoverageDetails.Modules) {
                    assemblyNames.Add(module.Name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```